# How do I tell my boss I don't want to keep working extra?

Tags: job-change, work-experience, promotion, career-switch

A year ago, I applied for a position that would have been a promotion for me within my company. I didn't get the job, but I was asked if I would be willing to fill in from time to time when some of the regulars take vacation, call in sick, etc. I thought it was a good idea and would give me the experience I need to get the next promotion. The problem is, I've found that I really don't like the job. In fact, the promotion job has less responsibilities than my current position! Whenever I fill in, I'm bored all day trying to find stuff to do to pass the time. Now, I want out of it. I'm just not sure how to tell my boss. I'm also doing some schooling and job training on the side so that I can eventually leave the company and go into a different field. I'm near the end of my schooling, and would really like to use my time off to work on my studies and not fill in for my coworkers. Help! How do I get out of this?!

My biggest concern is that if I tell my boss I'm no longer interested in filling in for the promotion job, I'm essentially announcing that I don't see myself having a future with the company.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Politely and professionally declining overtime](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/7095/politely-and-professionally-declining-overtime)

Answer (score 11):

If you have a good relationship with your boss, you can actually just go in and talk to them about it.

> Boss? You know that I applied for that promotion last year and didn't get it, but I've been filling in for people as needed since then.  I'm actually glad I did not get the promotion, because it turns out that I don't really like that work after all, and I much prefer my regular job.  Is there a way that I can quit doing this?  I'm not adverse to helping out as needed, but perhaps I can help out in a different area, since this is not going to be a direction I want to go in my career.

If your boss is reasonable, he or she wants you to be enjoying your work.  You're not saying that you don't want to help out, just not in that area.

Comment: And to be fair if that promotion route isn't something you like many companies are more than happy to move employees into different roles if the employee is interested and I'm able to do so. (I'd rather retain a good employee that I will have to retrain into a new role than lose a good employee and have to train them from scratch.)

Answer (score 0):

Well I hope you have a good relation with your boss if that is the case then no worries you can tell him directly or you can speak to him one to one. Or else just work normally in the usual working hours. But when it comes to extra working hours your performance should drop down. This should be continued for few days and in a week or so it should affect your daily work too. Make sure your boss notices this later speak to him one to one and express your frustration and tell him that extra hours are juicing out the joy of working from you and you can perform even better if you had more time for yourself. And convince him